# NAudio and Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, naudio

I would like to use Naudio library to record audio, add some effects and play the audio with android. I have a xamarin android app which I would like to add this feature. I saw WaveOut (and WaveIn) is for Windows only right?, So, should I need to implement an IWavePlayer using the android audio player? Is this another way to use naudio with xamarin android? 
thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like NAudio is a Windows only library.  I haven't seen anything about it working with Xamarin Android.  I believe that the library is based on simplifying the Windows based audio libraries.  You might need to leverage Android's native functionality, or another Android based library.  I could be wrong, and I'd be interested in seeing this work if it does.

Comment: More like a question that asks for recommendations. Microsoft later had a blog post on this topic, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A large part of NAudio is wrappers for Windows Audio APIs. There is some stuff that could be used cross platform, but you would need to create a native implementation of `IWavePlayer` and would only be able to use fully managed codecs.

Comment: by the way naudio is a great library. Are there implemented a noise gate effect or a reverb effect? if not, do you know where could I read a pseudocode to implement them? thanks.

Comment: I often port algorithms from musicdsp or jsfx examples from REAPER if I want to make an effect for NAudio. C# audio algorithm examples are in short supply unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This can be recorded and played back:

https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder

Page:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Switch x:Name="TimeoutSwitch" IsToggled="True" />
    <Label Text="Timeout after silence?" />
</StackLayout>
<Button x:Name="RecordButton"
        Clicked="Record_Clicked" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Text="Record" />
<Button x:Name="PlayButton"
        Clicked="Play_Clicked" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        IsEnabled="False" Text="Play" />
```

CS:

```
AudioRecorderService recorder;
AudioPlayer player;

public AudioPlayPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    recorder = new AudioRecorderService
    {
        StopRecordingAfterTimeout = true,
        TotalAudioTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
        AudioSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
    };

    player = new AudioPlayer();
    player.FinishedPlaying += Player_FinishedPlaying;
}

private void Player_FinishedPlaying(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlayButton.IsEnabled = true;
    RecordButton.IsEnabled = true;
}

private async void Record_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!recorder.IsRecording)
        {
            recorder.StopRecordingOnSilence = TimeoutSwitch.IsToggled;

            RecordButton.IsEnabled = false;
            PlayButton.IsEnabled = false;

            var audioRecordTask = await recorder.StartRecording();

            RecordButton.Text = "Stop Recording";
            RecordButton.IsEnabled = true;

            await audioRecordTask;

            RecordButton.Text = "Record";
            PlayButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            RecordButton.IsEnabled = false;
            await recorder.StopRecording();
            RecordButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void Play_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var filePath = recorder.GetAudioFilePath();

        if (filePath != null)
        {
            PlayButton.IsEnabled = false;
            RecordButton.IsEnabled = false;

            player.Play(filePath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I have tested it available and have updated the code.